# C# solution cant find type or namespace when debugging over docker-compose

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

**The problem:**

I'm running two ASP.Net Core Web-Apis in containers specified in a docker-compose.yml file.
These ASP.Net Core Projects are part of a solution with some other projects.
In my docker-compose file I specify a volume which maps my solution folder to both containers (for debuggin / dotnet watch).

When I start docker-compose I'm getting errors from Visual Studio Code and Rider like this: `The type or namespace name 'ISomeService' could not be found`

Also I have seen permission errors targeting files in the `/obj` and `/bin` folder.

When I stop the docker stack and delete the `obj` and `bin` folder of each project in the solution all works after a restore. But when I start docker-compose again I have the same problem again and have to do this procedur again after each change.

**My setup:**
OS: Linux
Docker: Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
Docker-Compose: docker-compose version 1.25.3, build d4d1b42b
ASP.Net Core: 3.1

**docker-compose.dev.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
...
api1:
    build:
      target: debug
    volumes:
      - ./backend/src:/app
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      API_ConnectionStrings__MyCon: 

  api2:
    build:
      target: debug
    volumes:
      - ./backend/src:/app
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      API_ConnectionStrings__MyOtherCon:
...
```

**Dockerfile (They are basicaly the same on each API)**

```
# DEBUG ##########################################
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS debug

ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER 1

# install debugger for Net Core
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/My.Api/

RUN dotnet restore

# RUN mkdir /out/
# RUN dotnet publish --no-restore --output /out/ --configuration Production

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "run", "--runtime DEVELOPEMENT"]

# PROD ###########################################
...
```

I have researched this problem now for over a week and cant find any solutions. Any ideas / suggestions? Is there maby an other way of dealing with debuggin and dotnet core (on Linux)?

*Sorry for my bad english.*

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem now by changeing the path of the `bin` and `obj` to a directory outside my mounted folder. This solved the permission problems.

To change the path I had to add a `Directory.Buid.props` file in each Project of my solution with following content:

```xml
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>/tmp/myapp/debug/obj/$(MSBuildProjectName)/</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
        <BaseOutputPath>/tmp/myapp/debug/bin/$(MSBuildProjectName)/</BaseOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This solution works for now, but can not be applied to a Windows Dev Env because of the tmp folder. What could work is to take a parent folder (not tried). If there are other solutions, let me now.